# Missing Values when comparing models (lme) - All fitted objects must use the same number of observations

Tags: r, mixed-model, missing-data

I am doing two linear mixed effects models using the nmle package and trying to compare them to see which one explain the better my dependent variable.

Here's some data as an eaxmple:

| Speaker | Item | Number of Syllables | Type of Accent | Duration of Syllable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Final Accent | 4.0 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | Final Accent | 3.0 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | Final Accent | 5.7 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | Initial Accent | 3.1 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | Initial Accent | 4.5 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | NONE | 3.2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Final Accent | 4.4 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | Final Accent | 7.3 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | NONE | 0.3 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | Initial Accent | 2.1 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | Initial Accent | 4.0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | NONE | 0.5 |

I’m interested in knowing the effect of the number of syllables and the type of accent in the duration of the syllable.

This is my code:

```
M1 <- lme(fixed = duration of the syllable ~ type of accent, random = list(speaker = ~1, item = ~1), data = my_data)
M2 <- lme(fixed = duration of the syllable ~ type of accent + number of syllables, random = list(speaker = ~1, item = ~1), data = my_data)
```

The thing is that every observation of the type of accent NONE, only has one syllable. Meanwhile, Final Accent has 1 and 3 syllables and Initial Accent has 2, 3 and 4 syllables.

M1 has 712 observations and M2 has 832 observations, which is why I get this error when I try to do an anova :

```
anova.lme(M1, M2)

Error in anova.lme(M1, M2) : 
  all fitted objects must use the same number of observations
In addition: Warning message:
In anova.lme(M1, M2) :
  fitted objects with different fixed effects. REML comparisons are not meaningful.
```

I understand this error, since there are missing values because not all type of accents have the same amount of syllables (for instance, NONE only has 1 syllable everytime).

I’m interested in doing a pairwise later in order to observe the contrasts between type of accent and number of syllables.
For instance :

```
NONE 1 – Initial Accent 1
Initial Accent 2 – Final Accent 2
```

This is because I want to see if there’s a significant difference in the duration.
I also know that the model would try to give me a contrast like this:

```
NONE 2 – Final Accent 2
```

But it won’t be able to because there are not “NONE” with 2 syllables.

My question is actually pretty simple, how can I deal with missing values in this case and how can I tell the model that there are some, without this having a negative impact on the model?
Furthermore, when doing the pairwise, how could I tell to the model to only give me the contrasts that are comparable?

I am very new with R and I hope my question makes sense.
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

EDIT : Here is `table(my_data_filtered$type_of_accent, my_data_filtered$number_of_syllables)`

```
       1   2   3   4
  AF   152  24 104   8
  AI     0  24 104   8
  NONE 288   0   0   0
```

Comment: So where you have `NONE` in Type of Accent, is this actually missing in the data (`NA`) ?

Comment: @RobertLong, no it is not. It's a Type of Accent called `NONE`. Is it as if was called `Unaccented`.  Meaning that the syllable in question is unaccented (as opposed to having a `Final Accent` or `Initial Accent`). There is still a duration value associated to `NONE`. 
However, all the unnaccented syllables (`NONE`) only have 1 syllable.

Comment: OK then I'm a bit confused. Why does M1 have 712 observations and M2 have 832 observations ?

Comment: I reckon it is because M2 includes the number of syllables as another independent variable. But the number of syllables isn't equal across all the "tpye of accent" variable.

`Final Accent` has 288 observations organised as such: 1 syllable (152 observataions), 2 syllables (24 observations), 3 syllables (104 observations), 4 syllables (8 observations).

`Initial Accent` has 136 observations organised as such: 1 syllable (0 observations), 2 syllables (24 observations), 3 syllables (104 observations), 4 syllables (8 observations).

`NONE` has 288 observations, all of which are 1 syllable.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense to me.  Intuition tells me there is a problem with missing values. Can you include the output of `summary(my_data)` by editing the question please ? And also `table(mydata$type_of_accent, mydata$number_of_syllables)`

Comment: @RobertLong I discovered wheere the problem was. I was using two different set of data for each model and I hadn't realised. My mistake. I corrected it and now I have the same number of observations, however when I proceed with ``anova.lme(M1, M2)`` it says ``Warning message:
In anova.lme(M1, M2) :
  fitted objects with different fixed effects. REML comparisons are not meaningful.``

And if I want to include ``type_of_accent:number_of_syllables`` it says ``Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) : 
  Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1``.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem with different number of observations is because a different dataset was inadvertently used.

Regarding the problem of

> ```
> Warning message: In anova.lme(M1, M2) :   fitted objects with different
> fixed effects. REML comparisons are not meaningful.
> ```

this is because you can't use Restricted Maximum Likelihood when performing a likelihood ratio test. You need to use Maximum Likelihood, so you can use the `method="ML"` option.

By the way, you may want to consider using `lme4::lmer` rather than `nlme::lme`. The former is the sucessor to the latter in many ways. There are a few things that `nlme` can do that `lme4` can't such as handling correlation structures and fitting nonlinear models, but in most cases it would be a good idea to switch to `lme4`

Comment: Thank you very much, Robert. I will indeed consider using lme4 instead. 
Do you have any idea of why is it that when I try to include  `` type_of_accent:number_of_syllables `` to my model, it says:


``Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) :    Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1 ``

I edited the original post and included ``table(my_data_filtered$type_of_accent, my_data_filtered$number_of_syllables)``

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error message because I don't use nlme much these days. Try the model in lme4.